# Getting an error on Sauce labs when trying to iOS native app : Error: Infrastructure Error -- The Sauce VMs failed to start the browser or device

Tags: appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

Here is my DesiredCapability. Trying to run native app.

Uploading the build from Saucelabs -> Live UI
tried a curl command as well

```
 MutableCapabilities sauceOpts = new MutableCapabilities();
//        sauceOpts.setCapability("name", methodName);
        sauceOpts.setCapability("build", "zzzz");
        sauceOpts.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.19.2");
        sauceOpts.setCapability("username", "zzzz");
        sauceOpts.setCapability("accessKey", "abcd");




        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
        caps.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceOpts);
        caps.setCapability("automationName", automationName);
        caps.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone 7 Plus Simulator");
        caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion","13.0");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "");
        caps.setCapability("app","storage:filename=zzzz.zip");
       // caps.setCapability("appium:autoAcceptAlerts", true);

    driver = DriverConfig.getInstance().setDriver(new IOSDriver(new URL("https://zzzz:zzzz@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub"), caps));
```

Comment: Can you submit this as a ticket for Sauce Labs helpdesk? Secondly, the `sauce:options` are not needed, please add them on the desired caps and remove `sauce:options` and try it again

Comment: Got the answer, I was using Real Device build instead of simulator build as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964374/xcuitest-simulator-architecture-appears-to-be-unsupported-by-the-appium